# Pandas DataFrame - How to apply Lambda Function on multiple columns and create a new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, lambda

Pandas DataFrame = df (example) is as follows:

```
----------------------------------
   col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4  ... etc.
----------------------------------
0  34.91   12.45    0.00  256.95
1   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
2   2.34  346.78    1.23    0.02
3   0.00   78.95   36.78    2.95
4   0.03   46.21  128.05   30.00
5   0.05    0.10    0.07    0.05
----------------------------------
```

```
df = df.assign(col_new_bool = lambda x: True if   ((x['col_1'] < 0.0001) and 
                                                   (x['col_2'] < 0.0002) and 
                                                   (x['col_3'] < 0.0003) and 
                                                   (x['col_3'] < 0.0004)) 
                                             else False)
```

I want to create a new column (named **new_col_bool**) in dataframe df.

**new_col_bool** will contain boolean **True** if all 4 columns have zeroes.

**new_col_bool** will contain boolean **False** if any of the 4 columns is non-zero.

Pls help with the correct lambda function ?

NOTE:
df has 100+ columns but my new_col_bool is calculated based on only 4 columns.
** How do I check a different threshold value for each of those 4 columns ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a lambda function for something trivial, use `DataFrame.all` over `axis=1`:

```
df['new_col_bool'] = df.eq(0).all(axis=1)

   col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4  new_col_bool
0  34.91   12.45    0.00  256.95         False
1   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00          True
2   2.34  346.78    1.23    0.02         False
3   0.00   78.95   36.78    2.95         False
4   0.03   46.21  128.05   30.00         False
5   0.05    0.10    0.07    0.05         False
```

To only check certain columns, select these first:

```
cols = ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4']
df['new_col_bool'] = df[cols].eq(0).all(axis=1)

   col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4  new_col_bool
0  34.91   12.45    0.00  256.95         False
1   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00          True
2   2.34  346.78    1.23    0.02         False
3   0.00   78.95   36.78    2.95         False
4   0.03   46.21  128.05   30.00         False
5   0.05    0.10    0.07    0.05         False
```

---

To check any condition:

```
cols = ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4']
cond = df[cols] > 0.5
# or cond = df[cols] <= -1.3
df['new_col_bool'] = cond.all(axis=1)
```

Comment: My df has 100+ columns and I need to check only 4 columns. How would I do that ?

Comment: How do I check a different threshold value for each of those 4 columns ?? Thanks for the prompt answers - appreciate it !

Comment: `.eq(0)` stands for "equal to 0", you can use any condition, see edit

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be efficient to transpose the dataframe and take the sum:

```
df['new_col_bool'] = df.T.sum() == 0
df
Out[1]: 
   col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4  new_col_bool
0  34.91   12.45    0.00  256.95         False
1   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00          True
2   2.34  346.78    1.23    0.02         False
3   0.00   78.95   36.78    2.95         False
4   0.03   46.21  128.05   30.00         False
```

Or for specific columns:

```
df['new_col_bool'] = df.T.iloc[0:4].sum() == 0
df
Out[1]: 
   col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4  new_col_bool
0  34.91   12.45    0.00  256.95         False
1   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00          True
2   2.34  346.78    1.23    0.02         False
3   0.00   78.95   36.78    2.95         False
4   0.03   46.21  128.05   30.00         False
```

To do by a threshold, use `max`:

```
df['new_col_bool'] = df.T.iloc[0:4].max() < 100
df
Out[1]: 
   col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4  new_col_bool
0  34.91   12.45    0.00  256.95         False
1   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00          True
2   2.34  346.78    1.23    0.02         False
3   0.00   78.95   36.78    2.95          True
4   0.03   46.21  128.05   30.00         False
5   0.05    0.10    0.07    0.05          True
```

Comment: How do I check a different threshold value for each of those 4 columns ?